# why do php variables need to be identified by $?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does PHP have a $ sign in front of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257460/why-does-php-have-a-sign-in-front-of-variables)

In languages like bash and Perl, strings need not be quoted and that is why variable access needs to be identified by using $. Why does PHP need the similar mechanism?

Comment: It doesn't "need"; it's just the way it is.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [historical](http://www.php.net/manual/en/history.php.php) decision, probably because it allows to include variables in a string literal:

```
$variable = "handle to data storage";
echo "a $variable";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because PHP is influenced by Perl. Back then, when it was conceived, PHP was just a set of Perl scripts.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>PHP Constants are a seperate type, but behave much like variables (except they can't be changed, of course... that's what they're constants for) and look a lot like 'em too. For readability, it's nicer to have an identifier. (<- random guess, not)</strike>

Besides:

```
$lol = abcdef;
$lol === 'abcdef'; // true
```

Undefined constants will throw a notice and will be interpreted as a string.

ohyes, and inside strings, variables can also be used, so an identifier is absolutely necessary (thanks to phihag)

Answer (score 0):

I think simply because without it mixing variable inside string will not be possible

```
$name = "bond";
echo "My name is $name" ;
```

Now without $ name will act as string .